# Audio file from the storage is not showing on the web page in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to show and play the audio file to a web page for my small Laravel project. The file is currently saved in the storage/app/public/audio/songs/. Here's how it shows on the web page.[audio on the web page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdjki.png).

Here's my code for the controller:

```
public function createSong(Request $request)
{
    // Initialize the $filename variable
    $filename = '';

    // Fetch the list of artists & albums from your database
    $artists = Artist::all();
    $albums = Album::all();

    // Validate input
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' => 'required|string',
        'artist_id' => 'required|exists:artists,id',
        'audio_file' => 'required|mimes:mp3,wav,ogg,flac',
        'duration' => 'nullable|numeric',
        'album_id' => 'required|exists:albums,id',
        'price' => 'required|numeric|min:0.00',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    // Handle audio file upload
    if ($request->hasFile('audio_file')) {
        $file = $request->file('audio_file');
        $filename = time().'_'.$file->getClientOriginalName();

        // Store the file in the 'public/audio/songs/' directory
        $file->storeAs('public/audio/songs/', $filename);
        // $file->storeAs('audio', $filename, 'public');

        // Create a new song record in the database
        $song = Song::create([
            'title' => $request->input('title'),
            'artist_id' => $request->input('artist_id'),
            'audio_file' => 'public/audio/songs/'.$filename,
            'duration' => $request->input('duration'),
            'album_id' => $request->input('album_id'),
            'price' => $request->input('price'),
        ]);

        if ($song) {
            return redirect()->route('admin.dashboard')->with('success', 'Song uploaded successfully');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Failed to save the song');
        }
    }

    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Failed to upload the song');
}
```

and here's the code for the blade view:

```
<audio controls>
                <source src="{{ asset($song->audio_file) }}" type="audio/mpeg">
                Your browser does not support the audio element.
            </audio>
```

I tried to debug it and here's how it shows in the web page: [debug output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bYhD.png). It's showing the exact data from the storage.

The result that I was expecting is for the audio to play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following...

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="{{ Storage::url($song->audio_file) }}" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Also, run the following command in your terminal:

```
php artisan storage:link
```